# Add a column with customers orders count at the time they passed the order

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table

| order_id | created_at | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 11 |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 | 12 |
| 3 | 2020-02-03 | 11 |

I would like to add a column "customer_orders_count" that will assign the number of orders that a customer passed to each transaction, ie obtain this table :

| order_id | created_at | customer_id | customer_orders_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 | 11 | 2 |

My problem it's I can't find how to calculated a local "customer_orders_count" dependind on each order, I only managed to add a column with the global "customer_orders_count" and for example for the first row order_id=1 I'll get customer_orders_count=2 whereas I'll like to be 1.

Does anyone has and idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Use cumulative `count`:

```
with mytable as (
  select 1 as order_id, date '2020-01-02' as created_at, 11 as customer_id union all
  select 2, '2020-02-03', 12 union all
  select 3 , '2020-02-03', 11
)
select *, count(*) over (partition by customer_id order by created_at) as customer_orders_count
from mytable
order by order_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by created_at) as customer_order_count
from t;
```

This is subtly different from using a cumulative `count()`.  This version *guarantees* that the numbers for a given customer are never duplicated, even when the dates are the same.  A cumulative count has no such guarantee.